# IvoryCKEditorBundle uploadimage can't parse JSON Response

Tags: javascript, php, json, symfony, ckeditor

I have Symfony 2 projekt with IvoryCKEditor integrated to Sonata. Also installed couple of CKEditor plugins. I have configured basic image upload, but I need to manage also drag and drop image upload.

Uploadimage [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_upload) says to configure `uploadUrl` property.

```
config.extraPlugins = 'uploadimage';
config.uploadUrl = '/uploader/upload.php';
```

My `app/config/config.yml` looks like this:

```
ivory_ck_editor:
    default_config: default
    configs:
        default:
            extraPlugins: "uploadimage,image2,uploadwidget,widget,widgetselection,lineutils,notificationaggregator,notification,filetools"
            uploadUrl: "/admin/sonata/media/media/upload?provider=sonata.media.provider.image&responseType=json"
            filebrowserBrowseRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_browser
            filebrowserImageBrowseRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_browser
            filebrowserImageBrowseRouteParameters:
                provider: sonata.media.provider.image
            filebrowserUploadRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_upload
            filebrowserUploadRouteParameters:
                provider: sonata.media.provider.file
            filebrowserImageUploadRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_upload
            filebrowserImageUploadRouteParameters:
                provider: sonata.media.provider.image
    plugins:
        image2:
            path:     "/ckeditor/plugins/image2/"
            filename: "plugin.js"
        uploadimage:
            path:     "/ckeditor/plugins/uploadimage/"
            filename: "plugin.js"
        uploadwidget:
            path:     "/ckeditor/plugins/uploadwidget/"
            filename: "plugin.js"
        widget:
            path:     "/ckeditor/plugins/widget/"
            filename: "plugin.js"
        widgetselection:
            path:     "/ckeditor/plugins/widgetselection/"
            filename: "plugin.js"
        lineutils:
            path:     "/ckeditor/plugins/lineutils/"
            filename: "plugin.js"
        notificationaggregator:
            path:     "/ckeditor/plugins/notificationaggregator/"
            filename: "plugin.js"
        notification:
            path:     "/ckeditor/plugins/notification/"
            filename: "plugin.js"
        filetools:
            path:     "/ckeditor/plugins/filetools/"
            filename: "plugin.js"
```

When `uploadUrl` is `/admin/sonata/media/media/uploadprovider=sonata.media.provider.image&responseType=json` error occurs [image]

```
Location: plugins/filetools/plugin.js
Description: An error occurred when parsing the upload response. Text could not be parsed to JSON.
Additional data:
responseText: Upload response text.
```

Apparently something wrong with JSON Response, **but file uploads to directory**.

My question is what should `uploadUrl` looks like?

Comment: and if you try install it without symfony ?

Comment: install what? ckeditor?

Comment: yes, IvoryCKEditor give you soo much problems

Comment: even if I was, I need anyway to specify ``uploadUrl`` which I don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uploadUrl` must contain the url of your script that handles file uploads.

So, if you used `uploadUrl` like `config.uploadUrl = '/uploader/upload.php'`,
You have to create a JSON response on your server side (upload.php file) to allow ckeditor to parse the response

See the example on http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_upload.

```
{
    "uploaded": 1,
    "fileName": "foo.jpg",
    "url": "/files/foo.jpg"
}
```

You have to get the file name and the specific url where you want to save on the server your files and create the response involved.

See (example in java server-side) :

```
out.println("{");
out.println(" \"uploaded\": 1,");
out.println("\"Filename\":" + "\"" + fileName+"\",");
out.println(" \"url\":" + "\"" + url +"\"" );
out.println("}");
```

Comment: First of all thank you for response. Secondly, Sonata Media bundle handles images upload. Ckeditor plugin Image2 uses ``uploadUrl: /admin/sonata/media/media/upload?provider=sonata.media.provider.image``, so I specified it in ``ivory_ck_editor`` configuration, but I'm getting error as described in question

Comment: I think Sonata Media bundle handles image through the file browser because the function linked to `uploadUrl` is expecting JSON response. Try to use `filebrowserUploadUrl` instead of `uploadUrl`

Comment: I ended up with writing custom UploadController. I don't really like that sf2 bundle's documentation is so poor. But thank you for help